# How to connect Excel with SQL Database?

Tags: sql, excel, data-analysis

I work as a consultant for a data-driven decision making consulting projects, so every day, I need to cleaning data, analyze, as well as, present our financial analysis. Most of our tasks require the same type of financial data as well as financial analysis, so instead of using Microsoft Excel to do this, which is quite slow for solving a huge amount of data, I would like to ask for your help that is there any simple model (necessary software, method of importing and exporting data among different software) for data cleaning and analysis by SQL and Excel?

Comment: Take a look at Excel's Power Query or Power BI. Both can deal with millions of rows of data from SQL and other sources. You could also look at SQL Server's Analysis Services to build cubes or SQL Server Integration Services to build data warehouses to use as a data source for Power BI, or Excel.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Smith. Actually, I have used Power Query (with and with out M code modification) and VBA for accelerating the cleaning techniques. However, they often come with a long time of processing for a large data batch. I have heard the SQL is a better option for querying data, but I have no prior experience in using SQL-related software. Therefore, I am very appreciate if you could explain or consult me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If using Excel 2019 try pressing the short key

Alt + A + P + N + D + S

or go to "Data" main menu, then in that there is a button "Get Data", then there is "From Database", then take "From SQL Database"

Specify the connection details and the query. The data will be loaded on to excel. From which you can start processing.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect SQL to Excel, beware of then using Excel as if it were a database itself. There are a couple of tell-tale signs that you are using Excel as a database, some are listed at https://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2022/03/yes-you-can-connect-excel-to-sql-server-dynamics-365-and-more/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32769786)